# How to stop tabs jumping when clicked (am already using return false;)

Tags: jquery, tabs

I have a simple tab setup here: http://jsfiddle.net/rX47q/1/

To see the issue, you'll need to crop the result so there is a scroll bar and scroll down so that the very first paragraph is cropped - now click a tab and you'll notice that the page jumps.

It's jumping to the top in the JS fiddle but on our test website it only jumps half way so I'm not sure this is the issue that `return false;` fixes.

Can anyone see what is causing this?

EDIT:

Solved by swapping out hide: `$(".tab", parents).hide();`

For fadeOut:  `$(".tab", parents).fadeOut(1);`

See: http://jsfiddle.net/rX47q/6/

Comment: Have fixed this issue using ````$(activeTab).fadeIn(1);```` instead of ````$(activeTab).hide();```` as seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/rX47q/6/

Comment: You could also fix the issue by simply using a more modern version of [jQuery, >= 1.8.3](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/rX47q/5/)

Answer (score 0):

The issue may be resolved by using any version of `jQuery >= 1.8.3`

[**JS FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/rX47q/5/);

Comment: Thanks for that, unfortunately our CMS (concrete5) forces a certain version of jQuery. Solved it by swapping .hide() for .fadeOut(). Cheers